# Struts Hibernate Spring Application with different database connection based on user selection

Tags: hibernate, multiple-databases

I have a web application that is based on Struts 2 , hibernate and Spring DI for integration. I have two databases and therefor i need to deploy two instances of my application one for each database. Now i want a single instance of my application to be deployed that work with both databases based on user selection. On welcome page i want user to select one option from DB1 and DB2 and as a result my application select appropriate session factory and assign that session factory to all my DAO classes session factory object.

Is this posible ?

Comment: Yes. But you will need to do lot work for that.

Comment: Please suggest how to do this?

Comment: See link here http://www.javabeat.net/2010/12/configuring-multiple-databases-in-hibernate/

Comment: In this link two SessionFactory objects are created in DAO class each pointing to a different hibernate.cfg.xml file and therefor two different databases. In my project all my DAO classes extends **HibernateDaoSupport** and perform operation in this way.. **getHiberTemplate().update(persistentInstance);** or **getHiberTemplate().find(Query)** etc.. How can i maintain such coding with multiple databases.